# How do I configure Travis CI build testing for a Java Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have an Eclipse Java project on GitHub. I would like to set up auto-build testing with Travis CI. However, when I enable build testing for my project, compilation always fails with the following error.

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

The command "ant test" exited with 1.
```

How do I configure Travis CI to run build tests for my Java Eclipse project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method is to have Eclipse generate an Ant build script for you.

Right click on your project in the Package Explorer and select **Export** in the context menu. Choose the export type **General -> Ant Buildfiles** and click **Next**.

[image: Export menu screenshot]

On the next screen, make sure your project is selected. You can keep leave the options on their default settings. Click **Finish** to generate your `build.xml` file.

[image: Generate antfile dialog screenshot]

Lastly, to ensure Travis CI runs the project correctly, [create a .travis.yml in your project's root folder](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/). For Java projects, it should contain at least the following.

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

script: ant build
```

Source: [Kofun devblog - Using Travis CI with Java Eclipse Project](http://kofun.pl/various/using-trvis-ci-with-java-eclipse-project/)